# How to override Backbone.js 's Paginator.requestPager setDefault function?

Tags: backbone.js, paginator

I'm using Paginator.requestPager in backbone.
And I wanted to change query paremeter value at time Collection fetch is called.
So, I added setDefaults function in Equipments.
But in this case Backbone.Paginator 's setDefault function will  not be called.
How to add some attribute's in Paginator requestPager?

```
var Equipments = Backbone.Paginator.requestPager.extend({

setDefaults: function() {
  var self = this;
  this.query = "nike";
}
…

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to execute original `setDefaults`

```
setDefaults : function() {
  // set own properties
  this.query = 'nike';
  // run super method
  Backbone.Paginator.prototype.setDefaults.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much,

I can call like this.
    Backbone.Paginator.requestPager.prototype.setDefaults.apply(this, arguments);

But I recognized I dont have to call super method.

I add a function and

```
setQuery: function (value){
    this.query = value;
},
server_api: {
    'query' : function() { return this.query },
},
```

I can do set parameter before fetch.